# What is the CBFC's definition of a Film?

Tags: content-rating

How does one decide which "films" need to be certified by the CBFC? Would a long special episode created only for television, with no theratrical release, require certification because it is called a "movie"?. Is a film defined in terms of its length or the format in which it has been released?

Comment: Not sure this is answerable here as (from some quick googling) you seem to be talking about a film censorship agency that works for the Indian Government.  Unless their documents and parameters are public knowledge (like that of the RIAA in America), then only a member of this organization can answer this.

Comment: Have a look http://cbfcindia.gov.in/html/uniquepage.aspx?unique_page_id=20

Comment: You said `which "film" needs to be certified by CBFC?` but as per wikipedia words CBFC assigns certifications to films, television shows, television ads, and publications for exhibition, sale or hire in India. So which film is not the case, every movie required certification.

Comment: @ankitsharma i think the intention is "how does the CBFC define films and when does one need a certification from the CBFC?"

Comment: Yes. The question os how dow does CBFC define films. The definition is pretty broad. It defines a "feature film” as fictionalized story film in 35mm or other gauges or in or
on video]2 [ tape or compact video disc.

Comment: The question is - will a long / special episode created only for television and never released theatrically fall under the definition of film (even though it may be called a movie). I posted this question since I saw posts about CBFC. Will TV exhibition fall under the definition of public exhibition.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean documentaries, when you say Long TV serials and programs (that is what I can think of, by long programs), then officially, they need to be sent to **CBFC** for review. I am not sure, whether CBFC actually awards a certification for the same. Reason being, if a certification is given, then it has to be displayed before start of the film/feature/ad/documentary.

As per the details present in the FAQ section on CBFC site, for normal TV serials/programs:

> Is there CBFC certification for TV?
>
> There is no CBFC certification for T.V programs and serials. However, under Cable
>   Television Network (Regulation) Act, 1995 content code / Advertisement
>   code have been prescribed for programme and advertisements appearing
>   in cable TV Network. The offences under Cable Television Network
>   Regulation Act being non-cognizable, a specific complaint has to be
>   made by an Officer authorised by the State Governments.

However, TV exhibition of a feature film, comes under purview of CBFC certification, and a film must be certified, before it is shown on TV

> Will it be illegal to screen uncertified films on the Cable TV?
>
> Yes. Only certified films should be shown on the Cable TV.